# Why are my testers not allowed to test my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode3.2

I'm using TestFlight so a few of my testers can test my new/first app. I went through the provisioning assistant to get all my certificates and profile info, followed their steps, used Build and Archive to create the .ipa, etc.

However, my testers are telling me their devices don't have permission. One of the devices is the iPhone 4S.

I'm using xcode 3 (newest version that my OS can have) and my base sdk is iOS 4.3.

Comment: Their devices need to be added to the provisioning portal, and to the provisioning profile you're signing the app with. It also needs to be an Ad-hoc distribution profile.

Comment: It's also time to upgrade your OS.

Comment: @Jessedc - I created an ad-hoc profile by copying the Release profile and setting my code signing to my provisioning profile I created. Most of the "how to create and ad-hoc profile" article a read required more knowledge of xcode than I currently have or seemed to say, "some magic happens", seemingly missing some steps assuming I either just know or figure it out.

Comment: I'm talking about the online provisioning portal at developer.apple.com - creating an ad-hoc distribution profile with all your tester's devices in it. You then use this profile to sign a release build.

Answer (score 1):

the device which your tester have ... you need to add their Device Ids in your account add those device in your provisioning profile build your app using that provisioning profile and give them It will work ...